# NSString memory lifecycle

Tags: objective-c

Trying to understand memory management in Objective C. Any help will be appreciated.

NSString *myString;

What above line does, does it allocate memory to myString? If so then how many bytes? 
If declaration of myString allocate memory to myString object then how compiler or runtime system will know how big string myString object will receive. I mean string could be of any length. So how much memory should be allocated?

```
myString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Testing String"];
```

What will happened to the memory when object is no longer in use? Will the memory be released or will it be occupied by the content of myString until app is running?

Comment: You might want to try to find a good textbook on object-oriented programming and study up on the *very important* distinction between an *object* and a *pointer* to an object.  Many would-be programmers founder on this topic.  (And you really should not attempt Objective-C programming unless you clearly understand the difference.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSString *myString;` does not allocate a string. Rather it reserves enough bytes to hold a *pointer* to a string; the lifetime of that pointer is dependent upon where in code the line is placed (and is not otherwise controllable).

`myString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Testing String"];` does the allocation*, and the string size is exactly enough to hold the string that results from your format; in this case enough for the characters "Testing String".

When the `myString` pointer goes out of scope, and assuming there have not been any other copies of the string, *and if you're using ARC*, the string will be deallocated. If you're not using ARC, you have the responsibility of deallocating it when you're done with it.

Allocation:
Generally speaking, an Objective C allocation will look like `pointer = [Class alloc];` and in practice it's more likely to look like `pointer = [[Class alloc] init];` (or any of the class's other `init*` methods). The `[NSString stringWithFormat:(NSString *), ...]` method is a convenience to lead to (either exactly or in essence) `[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:(NSString *), ...]`.

Comment: It should be noted that a classical newbie mistake is to do something like `NSString* myString = [[NSString alloc] init];  myString = someOtherString;`, thinking that you need to "allocate" the string (pointer) before you can assign anything to it.  At best the alloc/init is wasted motion; at worst (without ARC) it can create a serious storage leak.